# Python - trying to verify whitespace in calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

While starting to learn Python, I found a problem when trying to program a calculation using split. If I were to have whitespaces in my string

```
15 - 3
```

then the program runs fine.

If I didn't have whitespaces in my string

```
15-3
```

then I get an error message because split expected 3 values (the two values and the operator). I tried to compensate for it by using this:

```
num1, operator, num2 = input("Enter calculation: ").split()

if not num1.isdigit() or not num2.isdigit():
    print("Please use whitespaces in calculation")
else:
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    if operator == "+":
        print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1+num2))
    elif...
```

However, this still doesn't catch the error if I don't use whitespaces. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using it as a conditional, to catch IF I have a whiltespace or not in the value. So yes, i am asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: What part of this code you expect to "compensate" for no whitespaces?

Comment: The exact first thing you do is trying to parse `num1` `operator` and `num2` based on a whitespace split of the input. (see first line `.split()`). Based on this, you can not ever handle the case where there is no space.

Comment: My thinking was that if there is no whitespace, the first if statement should catch it, since num1 or num2 would not be a digit but would have an operator as part of the value

Comment: No, in the case there is no whitespace then the first line already behaves wrongly for you, and num1 num2 and operator are wrongly parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split` separates the string on spaces (by default) so if the user doesn't enter any, then the string is split into just *one* part and can't be unpacked into your variables.

I would handle this by either using a `try...except`, or by storing the whole input first and using the `count` method to check the user has actually entered the two spaces required:

```
inp = input("Enter calculation: ")
if inp.count(" ") < 2:
    print("Please use whitespaces in calculation")
else:
    num1, operator, num2 = inp.split()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this would make the most sense. Theoretically, I can still throw an error by being a dummy and using multiple whitespaces in the wrong places (like using multiple whitespace between the first value and the operator, and leaving no whitespace between the operator and the second value), but this would be the best option for others also beginning to learn to code. Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

The `split` line can raise a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack...` and as a result, your `if` checks are never executed (and they are sub-optimal too btw).

```
num1, operator, num2 = input("Enter calculation: ").split()
```

As a result, you have 2 options:

1. Check the passed string before `split`ting it:

   ```
   user_calc = input("Enter calculation: ")
   if ' ' not in user_calc:
       # do something about it
   ```
2. or wrap the thing in a `try`-`except` block:

   ```
   try:
       num1, operator, num2 = input("Enter calculation: ").split()
   except ValueError:
       # do something about it
   ```

Now it seems to me that regardless of which option you choose you would have to wrap it in a `while` to give the user the *ability* to correct his input without having to run the code again. For a detailed description of how to do that, look at this [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/6162307)

---

Note that option 1. in your case is not optimal though, because if a user passes e.g., `15 -2`, the `if` will not trigger and the `ValueError` raised.

---

So to sum up, I would do it like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1, operator, num2 = input("Enter calculation: ").split()
    except ValueError:
        print('Spaces are needed between characters!')
    else:
        break
# rest of your code
```

Comment: Option `1` wouldn't work in the case where they entered `"5 +6"` (not sure why someone would but  it's good to be complete!

Comment: @JoeIddon I was adding this comment to the answer. Simply trying to answer in a general way.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be the case, and indeed just tried it. I need to make sure there is a whitespace between the values and the operators, not just one whitespace. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
import ast

str_input = input("Enter calculation: ")

print(ast.literal_eval(str_input))
```

Comment: bit of a cheat for a beginner (not my DV, just saying!)

Comment: @JoeIddon, I like attracting such downvotes. Sorry, but too many homework assignments!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will try using it when I get a bit more advanced ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex and forget about spaces

```
import re

num1, operator, num2 = re.split("([+-/*])", input("Enter calculation: ").replace(" ", ""))

print(eval(num1 + operator + num2))
```

Comment: A bit complex for a beginner, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: This would hide input errors such as `1 5 - 3` because *all* spaces are discarded. Better adjust the regex to work with *or* without spaces around the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you could just want to prevent any spacing from altering your input. That is, remove all spaces from the string and then split() on the operator using `re`.

```
import re 
inp = input("Enter calculation: ")  # collect input operation from user
inp = "".join(inp.split())  # remove all whitespaces
num1, operator, num2 = re.split("([+-/*])", inp)  # split based on any operator in ['+', '-', '*', '/']
```

In that case, you can parse any tricky case like :
* `1+    12`
* `2-5`
* `1 *  5`